# Missing Deposit in my bitcoin core account

Tags: blockchain.info

I downloaded Bitcoin core to my computer and after that I bought some bitcoins. I didn't realized that my bitcoin core was not synced, after 3 days waiting to finish now my deposit is not showing in my wallet. What can I do?

Comment: Bitcoin core generates your addresses offline and even if sync is not completed. What is the address you generate using bitcoin core? And what is the tx of the transaction that the seller sent?

Comment: You "bought some bitcoins" can you say more about this? Can you provide the deposit address or transaction id?

Comment: @ShSh Please use comments instead of answers to ask for clarification.

Comment: you can use a [public blockchain database](https://blockchain.info/) to manually confirm the transaction, since all transactions are public knowledge. all you need is the address(es) involved. also be aware that addresses are tied to the key-pair generated for each bitcoin wallet, you should make regular backups of your wallet (keys) so you don't lose your coins.

Comment: as an aside, in case others are researching their first purchase, a good option is to use a web-based wallet to purchase coins, once you have your coins confirmed you should perform a small test transfer to your "core" wallet, you will lose a few satoshi dong this, but you will know your wallet is proper before moving a larger amount. it's possible to 'decirculate' bitcoin by sending it to an invalid/dead address -- plenty of people do this (typos, etc) and then wonder where their coins have gone.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on which wallet you 'bought' the coins. If it was a paper wallet/ mobile app wallet/ some other wallet software, then obviously it won't come up in the Bitcoin core wallet software. Just FYI, Bitcoin core comes coupled with a lot of other utilities apart from making you machine act as a full node. It has a built in wallet whose balance and other details are accessible via the command line interface, bitcoin-cli or the GUI bitcoin-qt.

Assuming you did not use the Bitcoin core wallet, you need to first import the private and public keys to get the balance. You can go through the API documentation of the bitcoin core. The following links might be useful

[Import address](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importaddress)

[Import private key](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importprivkey)

[Import wallet](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#importwallet)